# postgres full search work in development but doesn't work in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I have build PERN restaurant search like yelp with postgres and I added search option. in development everything worked but in production the server doesn't give any response. This is my first project with postgres.

This is the gin index I have created in the db postgres:

```
CREATE INDEX restaurants_idx ON restaurants USING GIN (to_tsvector('english', name || ' ' || location));
```

The server.js code:

```
// Get all Restaurants or search restaurant
app.get("/api/v1/restaurants", async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const { search } = req.query
  let response

  if (search) {
    response = await db.query("select * from restaurants left join (select restaurant_id, COUNT(*), TRUNC(AVG(rating),1) as average_rating from reviews group by restaurant_id) reviews on restaurants.id = reviews.restaurant_id WHERE to_tsvector('english', name || ' ' || location) @@ to_tsquery('english', $1) OR lower(name) like '%$1%' OR lower(location) like '%$1%'", [search]);
  } else {
    response = await db.query( "select * from restaurants left join (select restaurant_id, COUNT(*), TRUNC(AVG(rating),1) as average_rating from reviews group by restaurant_id) reviews on restaurants.id = reviews.restaurant_id order by location ASC"); 
  }
   
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      results: response.rows.length,
      data: {
        restaurants: response.rows,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

This is the react code:

```
const [searching, setSearch] = useState("");
  const handleSearch = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await RestaurantFinder.get(`/?search=${searching}`);
      setRestaurants(response.data.data.restaurants);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

 const clearSearch = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await RestaurantFinder.get("/");
      setRestaurants(response.data.data.restaurants);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  <div className="mb-2 add-rest-flex d-flex">
        <form className="">
          <div className="row ">
            <div className="col-auto">
              <input
                id="search"
                label="Search"
                className=" form-control"
                placeholder="Search"
                onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col tight">
              <i className="fas fa-search search-hover" onClick={handleSearch} ></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <button onClick={clearSearch} className="btn btn-primary col-auto layout-style">Clear Search</button>
      </div>
```

I think it is something with postgres but I don't have enough expreience. Does someone knows and can help me out?

Comment: There are many reasons for postgres to fail depending on how it is setup in production. In your local dev machine, postgres has access to entire RAM and can process huge data. In production if you are running postgres in a docker container then it will have limited resources to run your queries. COuld you please may be explain a bit on how is your production setup? like docker or Kubernetes or SAS etc

Comment: If you want help from PostgreSQL experts, you should edit the question and add the actual SQL queries that your code generates.